# Pygame Not Respounding

Tags: python, pygame

I am a newbie in Pygame (I use many libraries in python) There is a severe problem I face that is My pygame window is not responding I don't know why but this is happening every time I
run the code.

[Here is the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yhwdw.png)

here is the code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")

x = 50
y = 50
width = 20
height = 60
vel = 5

x1 = 100
y1 = 100
width1 = 20
height1 = 60
vel1 = 5

run = True

while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)



    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()


    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > vel:
        x -= vel

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 245 - vel - width:
        x += vel

    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > vel  :
        y -= vel

    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y < 500 - height - vel:
        y += vel
    
win.fill((255,255,255))  # Fills the screen with black
pygame.draw.circle(win , (255,0,0), (x,y), width)
pygame.draw.circle(win , (255,0,0), (x1,y1), width)
pygame.draw.rect(win, (0,0,0), (245, 0, 20, 500))   
pygame.display.update() 

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run = False
    
pygame.quit()
```

Could you just please help to deal wit this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). You have implemented an infinite loop, therefore the window does not respond. You need to draw the scene and handle the event **in** the application loop instead of **after** the application loop.

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")

x = 50
y = 50
width = 20
height = 60
vel = 5
x1 = 100
y1 = 100
width1 = 20
height1 = 60
vel1 = 5

run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > vel:
        x -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 245 - vel - width:
        x += vel
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > vel  :
        y -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y < 500 - height - vel:
        y += vel

# INDENTATION
#-->|
    
    win.fill((255,255,255))  # Fills the screen with black
    pygame.draw.circle(win , (255,0,0), (x,y), width)
    pygame.draw.circle(win , (255,0,0), (x1,y1), width)
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0,0,0), (245, 0, 20, 500))   
    pygame.display.update() 

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is caused by the indentation of your script.

`pygame.display.update()` will update the screen, that should be **inside** the `while run`!

The 'Fills screen with black' can be done **above** the `while`, since you want that just once.

Same story for the `for` loop that will set `run = False`, the button and event's is something you want to check every iteration, so move it inside the `while`

---

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")



x = 50
y = 50
width = 20
height = 60
vel = 5

x1 = 100
y1 = 100
width1 = 20
height1 = 60
vel1 = 5

run = True

win.fill((255,255,255))  # Fills the screen with black
pygame.draw.circle(win , (255,0,0), (x,y), width)
pygame.draw.circle(win , (255,0,0), (x1,y1), width)
pygame.draw.rect(win, (0,0,0), (245, 0, 20, 500))

while run:
    # pygame.time.delay(100)



    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()


    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > vel:
        x -= vel

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 245 - vel - width:
        x += vel

    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > vel  :
        y -= vel

    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y < 500 - height - vel:
        y += vel


    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: @Dr.FarsanaFarooq This does not work because the object does not move when you press the keys.